# Dynamic Property Binding for Angular Directive Inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, directive

Hi I'm making a a drag directive but because of the way it works I can't get it to work on dynamic objects as it calls the id in the input.

```
@Input()
set Drag(options: any) {
   this.stickerElement = document.getElementById(options.id);
}
```

Which works fine when the element isn't dynamic:

```
<div id="sticker" class="issues" [Drag]="{id: 'sticker'}">
```

but when it's set dynamically I can't figure out how to interpolate the ID dynamically.

```
<div [attr.id]="'Session' + Day.id" [Drag]="{id:'Session' + Day.id}"></div>
```

I've tried setting this.stickerElement with the @HostListener when you use it but that allows the directive to bubble and use child elements. I guess I can work around it but it doesn't *feel* right.

I feel like I'm missing some knowledge because no matter what I google nothing useful comes up about how to interpolate it correctly. Can you interpolate an attribute into a directive like this?

Thanks in Advance
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue in the interpolation. However, `document.getElementById(options.id)` in Angular looks dirty. Instead you could use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) and directly send the `HTMLElement`.

Try the following

**Template**

```html
<div appSticker #sticker [Drag]="{ref:sticker}"></div>
```

**Directive**

```js
@Directive({ selector: "[appSticker]" })
export class StickerDirective {
  stickerElement: HTMLElement;

  @Input()
  set Drag(options: any) {
    this.stickerElement = options.ref;
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

Also I don't see the directive binding in the `<div>` tag in your code.